# Why TypeORM repository findOne method are returning plain objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I recently realised on using typeorm that when I separate my entity definition from my model class and use the respective repository some methods as `findOne` are returning plain objects instead of model class instances. I would like to know if this is the expected behavior or if I'm losing something on my implementation.

The following code reproduce the described circunstance:

```
import { EntitySchema, createConnection } from 'typeorm'

class Nameable {
  id: number
  name: string
}

const NameableSchema = new EntitySchema<Nameable>({
  name: 'nameable', 
  columns: { 
    id: { type: Number, primary: true, generated: 'increment' },
    name: { type: String }
  }
})

createConnection({
  type: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  username: "logbook",
  password: "logbook",
  database: "logbook",
  entities: [ NameableSchema ], 
  synchronize: true 
})
.then(databaseConnection => databaseConnection.getRepository(NameableSchema))
.then(nameableRepository => nameableRepository.findOne({ where: { id: 1 }}))
.then(findedNameable => console.log(findedNameable))
```

In this case, considering that I have a persisted tuple in my database which id value is equal to 1, `console.log(findedNameable)` is printing out the following:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'NameableName' }
```

However, I was expecting something like that:

```
Nameable { id: 1, name: 'NameableName' }
```

I have done some tests using decorators in my model class and, for what I could see, in this case, all the instances returned by the repository methods were instances from my correspondent model class. This example using decorators indeed show the expected behavior:

```
import { createConnection, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm'

@Entity()
class Nameable {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  name: string
}

createConnection({
  type: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  username: "username",
  password: "password",
  database: "database",
  entities: [ Nameable ], 
  synchronize: true 
})
.then(databaseConnection => databaseConnection.getRepository(Nameable))
.then(nameableRepository => nameableRepository.findOne({ where: { id: 1 }}))
.then(findedNameable => console.log(findedNameable))
```

What happens is that I really would like o keep my entity definitions separated from my models, so I have not considered to use decorators to address this problem yet.

Also, I could not find anything in the documentation pointing out that having a separated entity definition would interfere in repository classes behavior.

Comment: There's a world of difference between `getRepository<Nameable>(NameableSchema)` and `getRepository(Nameable)`. If you have to specify a type argument explicitly, you are usually doing something weird.

Comment: Yes, no need for that type argument, thanks. Could you please be more specific about what do you mean by "world difference"?

Comment: Well, passing the class itself to the repository factory means it can use the class at runtime, say to create objects. Passing it as a type argument provides nothing of the kind. It is just erased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when using EntitySchema definitions separated from the model classes you need to specify a `target` value inside the `options` parameter indicating the class you want to map to. Also the `name` value should be equal to the model class name.

The following EntitySchema definition should make the question's code work as expected:

```
const NameableSchema = new EntitySchema<Nameable>({
  name: Nameable.name, // Or 'Nameable', as you wish
  target: Nameable,
  columns: { 
    id: { type: Number, primary: true, generated: 'increment' },
    name: { type: String }
  }
})
```